# yield content or yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm doing the following in my application template:

```
<%= yield(:content) or yield %>
```

I have a questions template that is nested within the application template.
However, for my questions index, I want just want to display the application template, not the questions template.

As such, I override it like this:

```
  format.html { render :layout => "application"}
```

This overrides the template fine such that the application template is rendered, not the question template.  However, it doesn't seem like the "or yield" statement is working; my content is blank.  It works fine when I change the application template to this:

```
<%= yield %>
```

I need the original statement though so I can have the nested template. 
I'd prefer not to have to write content_for's across the entire site in order to have a nested template.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

In place of

```
 <%= yield(:content) or yield %>
```

use:

```
<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but can you provide more details about your setup? I don't feel you are doing it "right", that is, I don't feel you need `yield(:content)`. I am particularly interested in the case where you actually provide `content_for :content`. Since you don't call yield (without params) in this case I don't understand why you don't simply provide the content for yield (without params) instead of having a `yield(:content)`.

Also additionally to the other answer you can also try `(c = yield(:content)).present? ? c : yield` in case that solution wouldn't work.